# Can babel CLI print debugging info?

Tags: javascript, frontend, babeljs, babel-cli

I'd love to know some stats like the before/after file size. Any way to enable this with babel CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Babel's CLI doesn't currently have any feature like this.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make a feature request when I have a second.